# jQuery Mobile - cannot properly update array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm experiencing what I believe is a logic problem in my jQuery code. I am creating an array of objects to be JSON.stringify'd and pushed to localStorage. The format is like this:

arr = [{"name": "Some Name", "number": "1"},{"name": "Another Name", "number":"52"}, etc...

There are a variable number of sliders on the page, each slider corresponds to a "name". And the value of the slider corresponds to "number". As the slider updates, it should update the appropriate "name" with the updated number.

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I can get it to do one of two things: add a new object in the array every time the slider moves. The result: [{"name": "Some Name", "number": "1"},{"name": "Some Name", "number": "2"},{"name": "Some Name", "number": "3"}]

OR, if I tweak things, I can get it to replace just the number and leave the name... until another slider is moved, at which point it erases the existing object and replaces it with a new object using the new name.

What I want is to have one object in the array for each slider. Since the number of sliders will vary depending on certain settings, I can't hard-code in IDs.

I'm sorry if this sounds complicated.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".init_slider", function() {
    init_val = $(this).val();
    char_name = $(this).parent().prev().prev().html();

    init_char_object.name = char_name;
    init_char_object.initroll = init_val;

// If the array is empty, push the object into the array
    if (init_array.length === 0) { 
        init_array.push(init_char_object);
    } else {

// Check the array for the current name. If it's already there, just replace the number. 
// If it's not there, push the new object into the array. 
        $.each(init_array, function(i) {
          if(init_array[i].name === char_name) {
              init_array[i].initroll = init_val;  // new add
              return false;
           } else {
          init_array.push(init_char_object);
           }
         });

// Update localStorage with the array. 
       localStorage.setItem("_init_data", JSON.stringify(init_array));          
    }
 });
});
```

Sorry again if this is confusing. I have a feeling that I'm making this much more complicated than it has to be...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of small mistakes.

Here is a fiddle with the working code:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8q4ss/**

in the change handler, you should create a new init_char_object each time (var init_char_object = new Object();) and then when checking if the name is already in the array, you need to iterate the whole array before inserting the missing name. I have used a boolean called foundInList which is false by default, and it is set true only if the name is found. Then outside the loop, if that boolean is still false, you can insert the name.  Also, the localStorage.setItem should be outside of the IF-ELSE:

```
var init_array = [];
$(document).on("change", ".init_slider", function() {   
    init_val = $(this).val();
    char_name = $(this).parent().prev().html();   

    var init_char_object = new Object();
    init_char_object.name = char_name;
    init_char_object.initroll = init_val;

    if (init_array.length === 0) { 
        init_array.push(init_char_object);
    } else { 
        var foundInList = false;
        $.each(init_array, function(i) {
          if(init_array[i].name === char_name) {
              init_array[i].initroll = init_val;  // new add
              foundInList = true;
              return false;
           }
        });           
        if (!foundInList){
            init_array.push(init_char_object);
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("_init_data", JSON.stringify(init_array));          
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I implemented your solution and it works great. Exactly what I was looking for. I knew I was close! ;-)